# USB 2 flash drives on windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive

I've encountered weird problem. After one of the Win 10 updates (currently 1803 build 17134.228) "My computer" stopped showing older usb devices (they're detected and show up under devices in both device manager and settings) in the explorer. USB 3 devices work just fine. Same problem can be observed with USB 2 flash drivers on another laptop with Win 10, but said flash drives work just fine on a laptop with Win 7. Anyone encountered this problem and knows how to fix it?

Comment: How are these devices formatted, and was this done on Windows 7 or on a previous version of Windows?

Comment: @harrymc NTFS and on Win 10

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of methods for fixing USB problems which you could try:

- Try connecting on other ports of the computer (plug-out all other USB devices).
- Try to connect via a USB hub instead of directly (plug-out all other USB devices).
- Try booting a Linux live CD/USB and see if it can explore the devices.
- In the Device Manager, if you can see the USB2 devices, uninstall them and reboot.
- If this doesn't help, uninstall the USB 3.0 Root Hubs and reboot.
- Search for drivers for these devices on the manufacturer's website.
- Try the Windows USB Troubleshooter in *PC Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot*.
- Use regedit and navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\<Device Instance Path>\Device Parameters`, and set `EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled` to 0.
  For more info see
  [this article](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/usb-devices-not-working-windows).

If all fails, then possibly these USB 2.0 devices are just incompatible with USB 3.0
on Windows 10.

Comment: My PC has both USB 3 and USB 2 ports. It's detected in both, shown in device manager in both and non-explorable in both, sadly. It used to work just fine until recently.

Comment: In Device Manager, see if the driver of the USB 3.0 Root Hub has been changed since installing 1803. Try rolling back the driver. If it works, ask me how to avoid such updates.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this was one stupid coincidence. Both USB flash drivers had bootable Debian Live on them. As soon as I formatted them (one via diskpart, other one through low level format tool) they started working fine. Note though, Win 7 declined to format them, even though it detected them. Just leaving it here in case anyone experiences this in the future.